# XML file not validating against XSD file

Tags: xml, xsd

I'm new to XSD. My XSD file is currently both well-formed and validating and my XML file is well-formed, but I get the following error when I try to validate it: "Error at like 8, column 33: no character data is allowed by content model"

It's not wanting me to put any text for the topic (I currently have PianoML as the first topic that is causing the error), but how do I fix that in the XSD? I'll post the full files at the bottom, but here is the code snippet that I believe needs to be fixed:

```
<xs:element name="topic">
    <xs:complexType>
      <xs:attribute name="genre" use="required">
        <xs:simpleType>
          <xs:restriction base="xs:string">
            <xs:enumeration value="ART"/>
            <xs:enumeration value="Music"/>
            <xs:enumeration value="Science"/>
            <xs:enumeration value="Technology"/>
          </xs:restriction>
        </xs:simpleType>
      </xs:attribute>
    </xs:complexType>
  </xs:element>
```

I've tried a number of things, but keep getting errors. I'm sure it's a really simple solution, but my rookie attempts and Google searches aren't helping.  How do I allow for that text?

Here is the XML file (presentations.xml):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<presentations xmlns="http://www.brett.com/presentations"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.brett.com/presentations presentations.xsd"
>

  <presentation date="2013-07-31" length="PT30M">
    <topic genre="Music">PianoML</topic>
    <presenters>
      <name title="Mr." id="Y258">
        <first>Elvis</first>
        <middle>A</middle>
        <last>Presley </last>
      </name>
      <name title="Miss" id="X365">
        <first>Lady</first>
        <last>Gaga</last>
      </name>
    </presenters>
  </presentation>

    <presentation date="2013-08-05" length="PT35M">
    <topic genre="Science">AlienML</topic>
    <presenters>
         <name title="Mr." id="Y007">
        <first>Will</first>
        <last>Smith</last>
      </name>
      <name title="Mr." id="Y360">
        <first>Tommy</first>
        <first>Lee</first>
        <last>Jones</last>
      </name>
    </presenters>
  </presentation>
</presentations>
```

Here is the XSD file (presentations.xsd):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
xmlns="http://www.brett.com/presentations"
targetNamespace="http://www.brett.com/presentations"
elementFormDefault="qualified">

  <xs:element name="presentations">
    <xs:complexType>
      <xs:sequence minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded">
        <xs:element ref="presentation"/>
      </xs:sequence>
    </xs:complexType>
  </xs:element>

  <xs:element name="presentation">
    <xs:complexType>
      <xs:sequence>
        <xs:element ref="topic"/>
        <xs:element ref="presenters"/>
      </xs:sequence>
      <xs:attribute name="date" type="xs:string" use="required"/>
      <xs:attribute name="length" type="xs:string" use="required"/>
    </xs:complexType>
  </xs:element>

  <xs:element name="topic">
    <xs:complexType>
      <xs:attribute name="genre" use="required">
        <xs:simpleType>
          <xs:restriction base="xs:string">
            <xs:enumeration value="ART"/>
            <xs:enumeration value="Music"/>
            <xs:enumeration value="Science"/>
            <xs:enumeration value="Technology"/>
          </xs:restriction>
        </xs:simpleType>
      </xs:attribute>
    </xs:complexType>
  </xs:element>

  <xs:element name="presenters">
    <xs:complexType>
      <xs:sequence maxOccurs="unbounded">
        <xs:element ref="name"/>
      </xs:sequence>
    </xs:complexType>
  </xs:element>

  <xs:element name="name">
    <xs:complexType>
      <xs:sequence>
        <xs:sequence maxOccurs="unbounded">
          <xs:element ref="first"/>
        </xs:sequence>
        <xs:sequence minOccurs="0">
          <xs:element ref="middle"/>
        </xs:sequence>
        <xs:element ref="last"/>
      </xs:sequence>
      <xs:attribute name="id" type="xs:ID" use="required"/>
      <!-- Edit 
      <xs:simpleType>
          <xs:restriction base="xs:string">
            <xs:patterrn value=""/>
          </xs:restriction>
        </xs:simpleType>
      </xs:attribute>
       End Edit -->
      <xs:attribute name="title" use="required">
        <xs:simpleType>
          <xs:restriction base="xs:string">
            <xs:enumeration value="Mr."/>
            <xs:enumeration value="Mrs."/>
            <xs:enumeration value="Ms."/>
            <xs:enumeration value="Miss"/>
          </xs:restriction>
        </xs:simpleType>
      </xs:attribute>
    </xs:complexType>
  </xs:element>

  <xs:element name="first" type="xs:string"/>

  <xs:element name="middle" type="xs:string"/>

  <xs:element name="last" type="xs:string"/>

</xs:schema>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your issue is that you have defined Topic as a complex type with no extension and only an attribute so the below lines are invalid due to having a text content of PianoML and AlienML respectively.

```
<topic genre="Music">PianoML</topic>
```

&

```
<topic genre="Science"/>AlienML</topic>
```

To achieve what you want you need topic defined as

```
  <xs:element name="topic">
    <xs:complexType>
      <xs:simpleContent>
        <xs:extension base="xs:string">
          <xs:attribute name="genre" use="required">
            <xs:simpleType>
              <xs:restriction base="xs:string">
                <xs:enumeration value="ART" />
                <xs:enumeration value="Music" />
                <xs:enumeration value="Science" />
                <xs:enumeration value="Technology" />
              </xs:restriction>
            </xs:simpleType>
          </xs:attribute>
        </xs:extension>
      </xs:simpleContent>
    </xs:complexType>
  </xs:element>
```

Answer (score 2):

Modify your definition of the `topic` element as follows:

```
<xs:element name="topic">
  <xs:complexType>
    <xs:simpleContent>
      <xs:extension base="xs:string">
        <xs:attribute name="genre" use="required">
          <xs:simpleType>
            <xs:restriction base="xs:string">
              <xs:enumeration value="ART"/>
              <xs:enumeration value="Music"/>
              <xs:enumeration value="Science"/>
              <xs:enumeration value="Technology"/>
            </xs:restriction>
          </xs:simpleType>
        </xs:attribute>
      </xs:extension>
    </xs:simpleContent>
  </xs:complexType>
</xs:element>
```

From the [MSDN documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms256106(v=vs.110).aspx), about `<simpleContent>`:

> Contains extensions or restrictions on a complexType element with
>   character data or a simpleType element as content and contains no
>   elements.